# Show a SVG image in a PDF render by reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, svg, reportlab

I'm facing an issue with Reportlab.
I have some troubles with images, for printing I need a full black image with no Cyan, Magenta or Yellow, I tried first with differents PNG, that's more simple to import but in all my tests there's still other colors.

So I need to import svg image but I have everytime an error, there is a simply way to do this ?
This is my code :

```
canvas = Canvas("*******\\test.pdf",pagesize=(dimX * mm,dimY* mm))
canvas.drawImage("app\static\img\Picto_CE.svg",25*mm,13*mm,width=22, height=5*mm,mask="auto")
canvas.save()
```

Everytime I tried this, I get the following error :

> PIL.UnidentifiedImageError:  fileName=<_io.BufferedReader
> name='app\static\img\Picto_CE.svg'>
> identity=[ImageReader@0x1decbca6f50] cannot identify image file
> <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001DECBDADFD0>

How can I solve this ? I already tried with renderPDF but it doesn't work.

```
drawing = svg2rlg("app\static\img\Picto_CE.svg")
renderPDF.draw(drawing, canvas, 25*mm, 13*mm)
```

Nothing appears in my PDF with that.

Comment: What leads you to believe that drawImage supports SVG? Doesn't it just support raster images?

Comment: I didn't know that when I tried first, but I don't know a way to import an svg image on my PDF file. And yeah it just support raster images. Do you know an other way to do it ?